# Typscript cannot import node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-fetch

I'm trying to import 'node-fetch'.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

But I seem to get an error.

```
C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\dist\http.js:7
const node_fetch_1 = __importDefault(require("node-fetch"));
                                     ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\dist\http.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\dist\http.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\dist\http.js:7:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\dist\client.js:11:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pat\Documents\GitHub\js\flux\backend\dist\index.js:6:34) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

My tsconfig can be found at https://sourceb.in/D5gqXavXF8

Comment: This usually indicates that you shoud change your tsconfig from `"module": "CommonJS",` to e.g. `"module": "ES2020"` but this might break other things if they can't work as ES2020 modules.

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json file add this compiler option

```
 "esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
```

If this doesn't work then you can do this depending upon your setup

```
// Do this if using JAVASCRIPT
const fetch = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));

// Do this if using TYPESCRIPT
import { RequestInfo, RequestInit } from 'node-fetch';

const fetch = (url: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(url, init));
```

Alternatively, you can downgrade the node-fetch package to version 2.6.6 and still use the require syntax. Version 2 of the node-fetch package is built with CommonJS.

You can read more about the breaking changes of the node-fetch package in their [GitHub upgrade guide](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-UPGRADE-GUIDE.md#converted-to-es-module).

Give this [blog](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-error-err-require-esm-of-es-module-node-fetch) a read as well

Comment: Thanks for the response! I already have this enabled by default, so this shouldn't be the problem or the solution.

Comment: @HippoBaguette can you share your tsconfig.json here?

Comment: Of course, https://sourceb.in/D5gqXavXF8

Comment: In your package.json file, what is the value of the "type"  property?  "commonjs" or "module"

Comment: I do not have a "type" property set, so i would assume perhaps the default?

Comment: Okay so by default value of type is "commonjs". In that case you need to use node-fetch@2 as per documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch.

node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require().

If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with CommonJS.

npm install node-fetch@2

Comment: Using the code in your answer some code has been able to run, and now a new error appears. https://sourceb.in/g2ZboItqqI

Comment: Which one you used javascript one or the typescript one?

Comment: Typescript, I'm using typescript so logically I used the typescript one